# Драйвера selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, драйвер

друзья.
Столкнулся с проблемой, программа перестала работать из за отсутствия нового драйвера для
Chrom Версия 115.0.5790.110 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)
На официальном сайте драйвера нет, как быть?

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает при запуске программы и на каком языке программирования вы написали программу?

Comment: Вот ошибка :  line 16, in validate_response
    raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}")
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115.0.5790

Comment: Написано на Python

Comment: Похоже, что [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76734820/there-is-no-such-driver-by-url-chromedriver), то что вам надо.